# unable to update table data in linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
bool check = false;
try
{
    var rows = (from s in db.logins
                where s.user_email == id && s.user_password == password
                select s).First();
    if (rows.user_email==id)
    {
        check = true;
        login login = new login();
         login.status= 1;
        db.SubmitChanges();

    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
return check;
```

i am trying to authenticate username password .if username password matches it automatically update status to 1 for same user in db.it matches the username and password .but unable to update it.

Comment: Where is the error happening in the above code?

Comment: `rows.status = 1;db.SubmitChanges();` Also use `SingleOrDefault()` instead of `First()`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It makes no sence checking rows.user_email==id after doing your query, since youre allready filtering everything that doesnt match in the query. Use SingleOrDefault, and check if Rows!=null. Do you get any exception? Catching e wont help you at all unless you run it in the debugger.

Comment: You do realize that any exception thrown from the code will be caught and then silently discarded?

Comment: Also, how does the setting the status property on the instance of the login type possibly affect what gets submitted to the database?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var rows = (from s in db.logins
            where s.user_email == id && s.user_password == password
            select s).First();

rows.status = 1;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Unfortunately the .net common language runtime which inhabits this dimension of reality requires that changes made to an object completely unrelated to another object cannot magically appear in that other object without the intervention of pixies and unicorns.